# Angular directive to change parent model, like ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I m learning "directives" and how are useful. 
My directive bellow, should increment by one on each click (both $scope.model and scope.bind ), but does not work.

Whats happening? i misunderstood?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.func = function() {
    return "text";
  }
  $scope.model = 1;
});


app.directive('myComponent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      class: '@',
      bind: '=',
      expr: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        console.log("click");
        scope.bind = scope.bind + 1;
        scope.$apply();
      })
    },
    template: 'Class: {{class}} Bind: {{bind}} Expr: {{expr()}}'
  };
})
```

```css
.sampleclass {
  background: #F00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <my-component class="sampleclass" bind="model" expr="func()">
  </my-component>
  {{model}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating the scope variable outside of angular you need to force `$digest`, you can use **[scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)** to force the digest cycle and have your bindings updated.

Try:-

```
     element.on('click', function() {
        console.log("click");
        scope.bind = scope.bind + 1;
        scope.$apply();
      });
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rpOYKb?p=preview)**

Alternatively you should just use **[ng-click](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick)** instead of binding the event using jquery. `ng-click` will make sure that bindings are updated after the handler is run.

```
....
  scope.increment = function(){
     scope.bind++;
    }
   },
   template: '<span ng-click="increment()">Class: {{class}} Bind: {{bind}} Expr: {{expr()}}</span>'
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ObNNnG?p=preview)**